# Vector search using mongoose and mongodb community edition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

- I need to get a way of implementing vector search on text , image and
  video attributes which are stored as document in Mongodb. I am using
  mongoose node package for model file for node js application.
- Is it possible to perform vector search using mongodb community edition? Or
  any alternative available to perform vector search. Please share a
  path to implement vector search for node js application with mongoDB without using mongoDB Atlas edition.

Comment: The community edition does not have vector indexes. Use ChromaDB, Weviate or one of the many open source vector databases instead or in parallel with MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks @FrancoisVanderseypen . I am using ElasticSearch now.